# woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees doesn't run after a failed Credit Card payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom code in a wordpress website where I add a fee if the payment method is Cash On Delivery. I do it like this through `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_handling_fee' );
function custom_handling_fee ( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $chosen_payment_id = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    if ( empty( $chosen_payment_id ) )
        return;

    $subtotal = $cart->subtotal;

    // SETTINGS: Here set in the array the (payment Id) / (fee cost) pairs
    $targeted_payment_ids = array(
        'cod' => 1.5 // Fixed fee
    );

    
    // Loop through defined payment Ids array
    foreach ( $targeted_payment_ids as $payment_id => $fee_cost ) {
        if ( $chosen_payment_id === $payment_id ) {
            $cart->add_fee( __('Fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee_cost, false );
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have the above code is not triggered at all in case of

- User makes an order with payment method 'Credit Card' with a bank redirection
- CC payment fails or user clicks on 'Abandon the payment' from Bank platform
- User is redirected to a page from the shop informing him the transaction failed, where he get a payment button which redirects him to checkout page
- User changes to Cash on Delivery

No added Fees from that page. But when I run the process from the regular checkout page, the fee is added.

Comment: Do you want to add a custom fee based on the payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You above code is working fine. I have tested and works but in order to add fees based on the payment gateway you have to trigger `update_checkout` to update checkout on method payment change.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_script_for_add_fess_based_on_payment_gateway' );
function custom_script_for_add_fess_based_on_payment_gateway() {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I already have this code to update it. Have you checked the above in the returned page and not the regular checkout page? Because, as I said, it works like a charm in the regular one, but if you fail to pay in the bank and then you return to the "payment link page", then it doesn't work